# Need help independently calling method: - (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note in iOS

Tags: ios, uideviceorientation

I'm writing an application that checks a device's orientation, and because of that, I have the following code block:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

which in turn, calls the following method:

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note {
    ...
}
```

What I would like to do is call the above method separately from the initial code block that I posted from a separate section altogether.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean to call it as instance method of class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do in this type of situation is pass `nil` as the argument:

```
[self orientationChanged:nil];
```

This depends on how critical the notification itself is to the implementation of the method. You may have to construct a notification with the appropriate information in it:

```
NSNotification *n = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"someName" object:someObject];
[self orientationChanged:n];
```

However, I have come to view this type of need as a code smell, what I try to do instead is extract the work the notification handler performs into a separate method and call that one directly, e.g.:

```
- (void)handleOrientationChangeForDevice:(UIDevice *)d {
    // do something here
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)n {
    [self handleOrientationChangeForDevice:n.object];
}
```

Then, in the calling code, you could do something like:

```
[self handleOrientationChangeForDevice:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, the first line in my method "orientationChanged" is: UIDevice *device = note.object;  Does this mean that my UIDevice object won't be valid?  If so, how do I avoid this?

Comment: @syedfa In this particular instance, you can likely substitute that for `[UIDevice currentDevice]`. But I have edited my question to take note of ways to avoid this situation in general.

Comment: +1 for "code smell". This is definitely the sort of thing where it's good to refactor a but, as suggested. (Cute turn of phrase, too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the device's orientation without waiting for the Notification, you can just get it this way:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  I don't have an issue checking a device's orientation, it's just that I am checking a device's state at startup, as well as after some movement, but in either case, need to call the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it by passing nil parameter or whatever object of type NSNotification you want to pass like

To call it in .m of same class-

```
[self orientationChanged:nil];
```

To call from another class-

```
[controller orientationChanged:nil]; //Declare method in .h first
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, the first line in my method "orientationChanged" is: UIDevice *device = note.object; Does this mean that my UIDevice object won't be valid? If so, how do I avoid this?

Comment: As you got your answer from @carl, I don't need to answer.